# packet sniffers and kernel bypass

Tags: kernel, packet, sniffer

Is packet sniffer software implemented as kernel bypass. if so, how (APIs) is it done on linux and windows?

or does packet sniffer actually depend on the kernel to talk to the NIC and put it into promiscuous mode. If so, again what are the APIs lin linux and windows

Answer (score 0):

> does packet sniffer actually depend on the kernel to talk to the NIC and put it into promiscuous mode

At least for the free-software packet sniffers, yes, it does.  (Some commercial sniffers on Windows might supply their own drivers, at least for Wi-Fi adapters, and bypass the networking stack for those adapters.)

> If so, again what are the APIs lin linux and windows

Linux: [PF_PACKET sockets](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/packet.7.html).

Windows: there aren't any nice APIs, so, for example, [WinPcap](http://www.winpcap.org) has to provide [its own kernel-mode driver](http://www.winpcap.org/docs/docs_412/html/group__NPF.html) which uses the [NDIS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff570021(v=vs.85).aspx) kernel interface.

Or you could just use [libpcap](http://www.tcpdump.org/) on UN*X (Linux, *BSD, OS X, AIX, Solaris, HP-UX, etc.) and [WinPcap](http://www.winpcap.org) on Windows, and let it use the appropriate capture mechanism and its programming interfaces on the OS you're using (take a look at `pcap-linux.c` in the libpcap source - it's a bit complicated to use some of the Linux APIs, for example).

Comment: so this does not really look like kernel bypass. for e.g. WinPcap works through the windows kernel by implementing filter device drivers. kernel bypass would be really bypassing the kernel like they do in high performance networking in the financial industry.